# Updating nested array value when child array is updated with $promise results

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, promise

I'm building a scheduler app using the FullCalendar component which is fed events from a nested array model $scope.eventSources consisting of multiple child arrays of events (gDataService.events being one of them). It uses $resource inspired by this plunkr example. http://plnkr.co/edit/pIDltQRV6TQGD4KQYnj7?p=preview.

When the following controller first runs, gDataService.events is assigned the function(start, end, callback)... as its value, and $scope.eventSource is assigned an array of 1 element (which is the function). The problem is when the calFactory successfully pulls the data from the server through $resource, gDataService.events is properly populated with event data, but $scope.eventSource doesn't (ie. still keeps the old value of 1 function element). I tried $scope.$apply, but it complains that digest is already in progress.

Your help is much appreciated.

```
myApp.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope,$compile,uiCalendarConfig, calFactory, gDataService)     {

var getEventSuccessCallback = function (data, status) {
    gDataService.events = function(start, end, callback) {
        var events;
        events = data.query({
          start: start,
          end: end
        });

        events.$promise.then(function(value){
           gDataService.events = value ;
          callback(gDataService.events);
    };

    $scope.eventSources = [gDataService.events];

};
})
myApp.factory("calFactory",['$resource', function($resource) {
    return {
        getEvents: function () {
            return $resource("/caldata/?c=to1_list",{});
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: You're assigning an array with a method that contains a callback to `$scope.eventSources` is that intended? Can't you just do `$scope.eventSources = events`?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `$scope.eventSources = [gDataService.events];` is defined within the function and should be defined in the controller, outside of the function. Try this:

```
myApp.controller("MainCtrl", function($scope,$compile,uiCalendarConfig, calFactory, gDataService) {

    var getEventSuccessCallback = function (data, status) {
        gDataService.events = function(start, end, callback) {
            var events;
            events = data.query({
               start: start,
               end: end
            });

            events.$promise.then(function(value){
               gDataService.events = value ;
              callback(gDataService.events);
            };
     };

     $scope.eventSources = [gDataService.events];
});
```

It seems you have a bracket issue there, since I see you also define a factory inside a controller.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I put it outside of the function definition as you suggested, but to no avail.

Comment: Regarding the bracket issue, I forgot to put the ending brackets here. Edited.

Comment: @javvvva Anyway you can set up a plnkr of your code?